# Fadeshow Not Showing Up On Page (Javascript/CSS/PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, css, slideshow

I'm building a site in PHP and have javascript code for a 'fadeshow' (slideshow with fades). I'm trying to test it out and it's not showing up on my site when I load it. I previously used a javascript 'slideshow' that worked fine, it just didn't have the nice fade that I was looking for so I substituted this in. The fadeshow box and images should be 1000px wide and 200 px high (which is in my code as well, just pointing out for clarification).

Here's the code:

My index.php:

```
<body>
<?php
include 'header.inc.php';
?>
<div align="center">
<table width="1000">
        <tr>
            <div id="javaphotos">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fadeshow.js">
        //new fadeshow(IMAGES_ARRAY_NAME, slideshow_width, slideshow_height, borderwidth, delay, pause (0=no, 1=yes), optionalRandomOrder)
        new fadeshow(fadeimages, 1000, 200, 0, 3000, 1)

        </script>

                 <!--Here's the Javascript code that DID work with the slideshow I had:

                 <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="js/slideshow.js" type=text/javascript></SCRIPT>

                  End slideshow code -->

                </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="body_box">
        <!--Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.--> </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="right-bar"><!--Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. --></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<?php
include 'footer.inc.php';
?>
```

Here's the .js file for the fadeshow (this is code that I basically copied and pasted and am using example PNG files for now just until it gets running):

```
var fadeimages=new Array()
//SET IMAGE PATHS. Extend or contract array as needed
fadeimages[0]=["slideshow/purplebackground.png", "", ""] //plain image syntax
fadeimages[1]=["slideshow/redslideshow.png", "http://www.funflies.com", ""] //image with link syntax
fadeimages[2]=["slideshow/yellowbackground.png", "http://www.javascriptkit.com", "_new"] //image with link and target syntax


var fadebgcolor="white"

////NO need to edit beyond here/////////////

var fadearray=new Array() //array to cache fadeshow instances
var fadeclear=new Array() //array to cache corresponding clearinterval pointers

var dom=(document.getElementById) //modern dom browsers
var iebrowser=document.all

function fadeshow(theimages, fadewidth, fadeheight, borderwidth, delay, pause, displayorder){
this.pausecheck=pause
this.mouseovercheck=0
this.delay=delay
this.degree=10 //initial opacity degree (10%)
this.curimageindex=0
this.nextimageindex=1
fadearray[fadearray.length]=this
this.slideshowid=fadearray.length-1
this.canvasbase="canvas"+this.slideshowid
this.curcanvas=this.canvasbase+"_0"
if (typeof displayorder!="undefined")
theimages.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random();}) //thanks to Mike (aka Mwinter) 
this.theimages=theimages
this.imageborder=parseInt(borderwidth)
this.postimages=new Array() //preload images
for (p=0;p<theimages.length;p++){
this.postimages[p]=new Image()
this.postimages[p].src=theimages[p][0]
}

var fadewidth=fadewidth+this.imageborder*2
var fadeheight=fadeheight+this.imageborder*2

if (iebrowser&&dom||dom) //if IE5+ or modern browsers (ie: Firefox)
document.write('<div id="master'+this.slideshowid+'" style="position:relative;width:'+fadewidth+'px;height:'+fadeheight+'px;overflow:hidden;"><div id="'+this.canvasbase+'_0" style="position:absolute;width:'+fadewidth+'px;height:'+fadeheight+'px;top:0;left:0;filterrogidX ImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=10);opacity:0.1;-moz-opacity:0.1;-khtml-opacity:0.1;background-color:'+fadebgcolor+'"></div><div id="'+this.canvasbase+'_1" style="position:absolute;width:'+fadewidth+'px;height:'+fadeheight+'px;top:0;left:0;filterro  gidX ImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=10);opacity:0.1;-moz-opacity:0.1;-khtml-opacity:0.1;background-color:'+fadebgcolor+'"></div></div>')
else
document.write('<div><img name="defaultslide'+this.slideshowid+'" src="'+this.postimages[0].src+'"></div>')

if (iebrowser&&dom||dom) //if IE5+ or modern browsers such as Firefox
this.startit()
else{
this.curimageindex++
setInterval("fadearray["+this.slideshowid+"].rotateimage()", this.delay)
}
}

function fadepic(obj){
if (obj.degree<100){
obj.degree+=10
if (obj.tempobj.filters&&obj.tempobj.filters[0]){
if (typeof obj.tempobj.filters[0].opacity=="number") //if IE6+
obj.tempobj.filters[0].opacity=obj.degree
else //else if IE5.5-
obj.tempobj.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+obj.degree+")"
}
else if (obj.tempobj.style.MozOpacity)
obj.tempobj.style.MozOpacity=obj.degree/101
else if (obj.tempobj.style.KhtmlOpacity)
obj.tempobj.style.KhtmlOpacity=obj.degree/100
else if (obj.tempobj.style.opacity&&!obj.tempobj.filters)
obj.tempobj.style.opacity=obj.degree/101
}
else{
clearInterval(fadeclear[obj.slideshowid])
obj.nextcanvas=(obj.curcanvas==obj.canvasbase+"_0")? obj.canvasbase+"_0" : obj.canvasbase+"_1"
obj.tempobj=iebrowser? iebrowser[obj.nextcanvas] : document.getElementById(obj.nextcanvas)
obj.populateslide(obj.tempobj, obj.nextimageindex)
obj.nextimageindex=(obj.nextimageindex<obj.postimages.length-1)? obj.nextimageindex+1 : 0
setTimeout("fadearray["+obj.slideshowid+"].rotateimage()", obj.delay)
}
}

fadeshow.prototype.populateslide=function(picobj, picindex){
var slideHTML=""
if (this.theimages[picindex][1]!="") //if associated link exists for image
slideHTML='<a href="'+this.theimages[picindex][1]+'" target="'+this.theimages[picindex][2]+'">'
slideHTML+='<img src="'+this.postimages[picindex].src+'" border="'+this.imageborder+'px">'
if (this.theimages[picindex][1]!="") //if associated link exists for image
slideHTML+='</a>'
picobj.innerHTML=slideHTML
}


fadeshow.prototype.rotateimage=function(){
if (this.pausecheck==1) //if pause onMouseover enabled, cache object
var cacheobj=this
if (this.mouseovercheck==1)
setTimeout(function(){cacheobj.rotateimage()}, 100)
else if (iebrowser&&dom||dom){
this.resetit()
var crossobj=this.tempobj=iebrowser? iebrowser[this.curcanvas] : document.getElementById(this.curcanvas)
crossobj.style.zIndex++
fadeclear[this.slideshowid]=setInterval("fadepic(fadearray["+this.slideshowid+"])",50)
this.curcanvas=(this.curcanvas==this.canvasbase+"_0")? this.canvasbase+"_1" : this.canvasbase+"_0"
}
else{
var ns4imgobj=document.images['defaultslide'+this.slideshowid]
ns4imgobj.src=this.postimages[this.curimageindex].src
}
this.curimageindex=(this.curimageindex<this.postimages.length-1)? this.curimageindex+1 : 0
}

fadeshow.prototype.resetit=function(){
this.degree=10
var crossobj=iebrowser? iebrowser[this.curcanvas] : document.getElementById(this.curcanvas)
if (crossobj.filters&&crossobj.filters[0]){
if (typeof crossobj.filters[0].opacity=="number") //if IE6+
crossobj.filters(0).opacity=this.degree
else //else if IE5.5-
crossobj.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+this.degree+")"
}
else if (crossobj.style.MozOpacity)
crossobj.style.MozOpacity=this.degree/101
else if (crossobj.style.KhtmlOpacity)
crossobj.style.KhtmlOpacity=this.degree/100
else if (crossobj.style.opacity&&!crossobj.filters)
crossobj.style.opacity=this.degree/101
}


fadeshow.prototype.startit=function(){
var crossobj=iebrowser? iebrowser[this.curcanvas] : document.getElementById(this.curcanvas)
this.populateslide(crossobj, this.curimageindex)
if (this.pausecheck==1){ //IF SLIDESHOW SHOULD PAUSE ONMOUSEOVER
var cacheobj=this
var crossobjcontainer=iebrowser? iebrowser["master"+this.slideshowid] : document.getElementById("master"+this.slideshowid)
crossobjcontainer.onmouseover=function(){cacheobj.mouseovercheck=1}
crossobjcontainer.onmouseout=function(){cacheobj.mouseovercheck=0}
}
this.rotateimage()
}
```

Any ideas of where to start looking to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use jquery

you can use the function http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

or you can even install a library there plenty of them
here is a suggestion
http://www.pikachoose.com/

does that solve your problem?

Comment: Ah yeah, Pikachoose looks classy, much more elegant than what I was trying to do. Thanks, I'll go with that.